# How to change Textbox text with each scanned barcode and fire ontextchange event

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, textbox, barcode-scanner

I am trying to change a text inside textbox everytime a barcode scanned. My program was able to take the scanned barcode and fetch the data from database based on the barcode text using ontextchange event, but when I scanned a barcode on the second time it added the barcode next to the first barcode input. 
for example :

1. 00111104
2. 0011110400111105

I am facing two error in here:

First, the barcode scanned was added next to the first one.

Second, ontextchange event can't fire without taking the focus outside textbox.
I am using asp.net using vb as code behind. Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub selectData()     
    sql = "Select * from tbl_Take where [Badge ID] = '" + txtScanID.Text + "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)

    drDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While (drDataReader.Read())
        'Taking the data from database'

       End While

End Sub

Protected Sub txtScanID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtScanID.TextChanged
    Call SelectedData()
End Sub
```

I set the focus on txtScanID inside page load.

Can you help me how to make the current barcode scanned replace the last barcode in textbox.
is there any other way to fire ontextchange?

Thanks in advances. I really appreciate the though.

Comment: Why dont you try clear the txtScanID.Text data after textchange action in code?

Comment: OMG... it never crossed my mind... I am trying to solved it by adding lostfocus event before. thanks for your suggestion...